# django clear all users from a many-to-many table relationship based on a filter

Tags: django, django-views

I am attempting to clear all the users from a table called `Team` based on two factors:

1. `team_id`
2. a custom variable in the user profile called `level`

Bellow is my current effort, I am well aware this is does not work but at least it's a starting point.

```
team = Team.objects.get(pk = team_id)
team_user_list = team.users.all().filter(userprofile__level = 1)
team_user_list.users.clear()
```

Note: I don't want to delete the users, simply remove them from the team table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`team_user_list` is queryset, so it doesn't have `users` attribute. Try

```
team = Team.objects.get(pk = team_id)
filtered = team.users.filter(userprofile__level = 1)
team.users.remove(*filtered)
```

Comment: This was my starting point as well, and just in case I had made a mistake I tried it again.  The result was the error "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'clear'"

Comment: Probably you will have to convert `filtered` to list

Comment: That got it! It worked without converting filtered to list to.